# How to load local json file in ionic cordova on android device

Tags: android, angularjs, json, cordova, ionic-framework

This here is my angular controller :

```
.controller( 'QuestionsController', function( $scope, $state, $http, $ionicSlideBoxDelegate, $q ) {
var answer = null;  // global answer variable
var totalScore = 0; // global totalScore variable

$scope.init = function() {
    // the question number
    $scope.questionNumber = 1;

    $scope.getQuestions().then( function( res ) {
        alert( res );
        $scope.questionList = res;
    }, function( err ) {
        alert( err );
        console.log( status );
    })
};

// this fetches the questions from the json data source.
$scope.getQuestions = function() {
    var defer = $q.defer();

    $http.get( 'data/data.json' ).success( function( data ) {
        defer.resolve( data );
    }, function( status ) {
        defer.reject( status );
    });

    return defer.promise;
};
```

I have tried replacing the json file path to the following and it still doesn't work:

```
$http.get('file:///android_asset/www/data/data.json')

$http.get('./data/data.json')
```

I really need help, and running on android version 5.1 (Lollipop)

Comment: What is your file structure ?

Answer (score 0):

The angular `$http.get` is return a httpPromise

it has three methods, `then`, `catch`, `finally`

no `success` or `error`

see https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q (The Promise API)

so, your just need modify your code to

```
$http.get( 'data/data.json' ).then( function( data ) {
    defer.resolve( data );
}, function( status ) {
    defer.reject( status );
});
```

Comment: Works perfectly fine in my browser but not on Android device

Answer (score 0):

> You can use like this

```
 $http.get('data/data.json')
        .then(function(response){
           $scope.data1=response.data;

        },function(error){
          $log.error(error);
      });
```

Comment: Works perfectly fine in my browser but not on Android device

Answer (score 0):

Just something to check - android file requests are case sensitive. Wrongly cased filenames in the $http.get will work on the browser but not on the device so a call to Friends.json is different to friends.json

Answer (score 0):

```
$http.get('js/contactos.json').then(
                function(response){
                    console.info(response.data);
                },function(error){
                    console.error(error);
                });
```

my json file path is: www/js/contactos.json